Carousel styles not loading in primeng 16
I have a simple project with Angular and Primeng 16
I use the carousel, everything is fine, but as soon as I press the next or prev button, the information does not load.
I have put all its style dependencies in the styles section of Angular.json
"styles": [
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],

And also my code example is like this
html file
<div class="card">
    <p-carousel [value]="products" [numVisible]="3" [numScroll]="3" [circular]="false"
        [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions">
        <ng-template let-product pTemplate="item">
            <h4 class="mb-1">{{ product.name }}</h4>
        </ng-template>
    </p-carousel>
</div>

typescript file
  products : any[] | undefined;

  responsiveOptions: any[] | undefined;


  ngOnInit() {
    
    this.responsiveOptions = [
      {
        breakpoint: '1199px',
        numVisible: 1,
        numScroll: 1
      },
      {
        breakpoint: '991px',
        numVisible: 2,
        numScroll: 1
      },
      {
        breakpoint: '767px',
        numVisible: 1,
        numScroll: 1
      }
    ];

    this.products = [
      {name : 7},
      {name : 8},
      {name : 9},
      {name : 0},
      {name : 1},
      {name : 2},
      {name : 3}
    ]
  }


I tried your code and i got an error :

Type any[] | undefined is not assignable to type any[]

You can correct it simply by doing:
  products : any[] = [];

What does it say in your console ?
